# Hydrating DATETIME fields in a random Doctrine DQL query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have a DQL query which contains a lot of `DATETIME` fields from multiple entities and uses aggregation functions as well.

The fields of entity classes themselves have the proper annotations like so:

```
@Column(name="transaction_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
```

Is it possible to get them as `DateTime` objects instead of strings?

Just take a look at the following DQL query for instance:

```
SELECT MIN(e.orderDate), MAX(e2.transactionDate)
FROM Entry1 e 
INNER JOIN e.joinedEntry2 e2
WHERE e.order = ?1
```

When using `$query->getResult()`, I would get an array with two strings (instead with two `DateTime` instances) regardless of the hydration mode I am using.